# install pymc3 on raspberry

Tags: software-installation, pip

I would like to install `pymc3` on my raspberry pi 3 model b+ for my hobby project. But installing `pymc3` by `pip` took forever and it was never able to finish installing. It there any other way to install `pymc3` on my raspberry pi?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? `it was never able to finish installing`... Does this mean there was an error? If so, what was the error? If there wasn't an error, then why couldn't it finish installing? Have you done your own research? Have you tried compiling `pymc3` from source on your own (if even applicable for this library)?

Comment: What is `pymc3`? Is it: "*Applications and toolkit for X-ray fluorescence analysis*"?

Comment: @Ingo `pymc3` is a python package for statistic modeling

Comment: @scitronboy `it was never able to finish installing` means after executing `pip install pymc3`, my raspberry pi died.

Comment: @407Peezy The Raspberry pi died??? What power supply are you using? Make sure it's rated at least 2A.